# How to show Non-PNP Devices in Windows 8/8.1/10

Tags: windows-8, windows-10

According to this [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/29f20043-f0ec-4358-a186-f9b0e2353ea5/nonpresent-hidden-devices-are-shown-automatically-no-need-for-devmgrshownonpresentdevices?forum=w8itprogeneral), Microsoft decided to remove non-pnp devices in windows 8/8.1/10. Thus, the variable tweak **set DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES=1** is no longer working.

I tried to copy the files: devmgmt.msc, devmgr.dll, dmocx.dll from Windows 7 to use in Windows 8 but that didn't work.
Is there some alternate way to show those devices without using a 3rd party application?

Comment: Nonpresent devices are now visible when showing hidden devices. Is this what you’re looking for?

Comment: No, I'm looking for the Non-PNP Devices, not non-existing devices.

Comment: Is there a specific issue you’re hoping to resolve?

Comment: No, I just want a native way to see those types of devices without using 3rd party software. It'll prove useful in the future.